# how to show single dot using custom Number pad in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, numpad

i am creating custom NumberPad

```
if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 4.1)) {
    inputBoxTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
}
```

my problem is, i want to display dot only one time.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber* candidateNumber;

NSString* candidateString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

range = NSMakeRange(0, [candidateString length]);

[numberFormatter getObjectValue:&candidateNumber forString:candidateString range:&range error:nil];

if (([candidateString length] > 0) && (candidateNumber == nil || range.length < [candidateString length])) {

    return NO;
}
else {
    return YES; } }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to allow the user to enter only one dot, you can use the delegate method

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

And simply check if the textField already contains a dot.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code. Works perfectly for me and with less code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *decimalSymbol = [numberFormatter decimalSeparator];

    if(([textField.text rangeOfString:decimalSymbol].location != NSNotFound) &&
       ([string rangeOfString:decimalSymbol].location != NSNotFound)) {
        return NO;
    }
return YES; 
}
```